# Altbeacon Launching in the Background detection time issue

Tags: android, ibeacon-android, altbeacon

I am using [altbeacon](https://github.com/AltBeacon) lib for detecting ibeacons. If I detect ibeacons from activity by starting service its detecting ibeacons perfectly fine.

Now I want to start the same operation in background(STICKY service). I followed [this](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/background_launching.html) document.
It is detecting ibeacons but problem is with time. It is taking too long to detect. I kept period to detect as below.

```
public class Ibeaconpocsuper extends Application implements BootstrapNotifier {
private RegionBootstrap regionBootstrap;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    init();
}

private void init() {
    BeaconManager beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
    beaconManager.setBackgroundScanPeriod(1100l);
    beaconManager.setBackgroundBetweenScanPeriod(1100l);

    Region region = new Region("com.exe", null, null, null);
    regionBootstrap = new RegionBootstrap(this, region);


}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
public void didDetermineStateForRegion(int arg0, Region arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void didEnterRegion(Region arg0) {
    showNotification() ;

}

@Override
public void didExitRegion(Region arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

private void showNotification() {
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher).setContentTitle("My notification")
            .setContentText("Contentttttttt").setAutoCancel(true);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, IbeaconNotificationActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());

}
```

}

Comment: How long is it taking to detect?  Have you added the two code lines you reference to set the background scan period?  Can you show where in code you put these lines?

Comment: I have used it in my application class, Updated question

Comment: @davidgyoung i have made some edits to ask my own question as well can you please suggest a solution thanks.

Comment: How long is it taking to detect?  Based on the code shown detections should take place within 2.2 seconds.